# Spring web services validation

Tags: web-services, spring, interceptor

I've two kinds of webservices:

1. webservices that need the request to be validated
2. others that must not be validated by Spring.

Is this possible in Spring?

I know about `ValidatingInterceptor`, but can we have two of these?

The reason for not validating one type of web service is that the request is not defined: what's sent in the request, depends on many things.

I am using Spring 3.0, with schema XSD's for my webservices.

Any suggestions?
Adi

Comment: What sort of validation?  If you have an XML schema, then you can validate the syntax against that.

Comment: Yes, I am using XSD to validate for case 1 WS using ValidatingInterceptor. My problem is how can I configure Spring to validate some and ignore some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `payloadroot` within a interceptor for that purpose.

All you need to do is to set `validateRequest`/`validateResponse` as true or false as required.

Here is a sample:

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="uri1">
        <bean id="validator1forUri1"
            class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor"
            p:schema="classpath:/WEB-INF/xsds/tovalidate.xsd" p:validateRequest="true"
            p:validateResponse="true" />
    </sws:payloadRoot>

    <sws:payloadRoot namespaceUri="uri2">
        <bean id="validator2forUri2"
            class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor"
            p:schema="classpath:/WEB-INF/xsds/nottovalidate.xsd"
            p:validateRequest="false" p:validateResponse="false" />
    </sws:payloadRoot>
</sws:interceptors>
```